# Output an array to the first sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Id like to output the list of sheet names obtained from this loop, to the first sheet

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetNameArray = [];
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
  sheetNameArray.push(sheets[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want to do? This script imports sheet names in the opened spreadsheet to the current sheet.

#### Flow :

1. Retrieve sheets from the opened spreadsheet.
2. Create 2 dimensional array to using `setValues()`.
3. Import the created data to the current sheet.

#### Sample script :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
var sheetNameArray = sheets.map(function(e){return [e.getName()]});
ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, sheetNameArray.length, sheetNameArray[0].length).setValues(sheetNameArray);
```

#### Note :

- If you want to import the sheet name to a row, please use this `var sheetNameArray = [sheets.map(function(e){return e.getName()})];` instead of `var sheetNameArray = sheets.map(function(e){return [e.getName()]});`

#### Reference :

- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Yes, id like to get sheet names and reorder them based on a value in cell 3,5 on each one

Comment: so the one with the highest value would be the first sheet, is there a function for that?

Comment: @user718229 I'm sorry. I cannot understand what you want to do. I seemed that my understanding for your question was wrong. I'm really sorry for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of what you want to do?

Comment: no you were right. I sort of changed what I was asking in the comment. Ive asked it in a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49266713/

Comment: @user718229 Thank you for your response. I would like to see it.