# Arrange sheets by value Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a function to reorder the tabs in Google Sheets? We'd like to arrange them on a specific value obtained on each of them,

```
  /** ... */
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Store all the worksheets in this array
  var sheetNameArray = [];
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    z = sheets[i].getRange(3, 5);
    z = z.getValue();

    sheetNameArray.push(z);
  }
  /** Use value in array to reorder sheets */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to reorder the sheets in the opened spreadsheet using the sheet names in `sheetNameArray`. If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? This sample script reorders sheets in the opened spreadsheet using `moveActiveSheet()`.

#### Sample script :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetNameArray = [];
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
  z = sheets[i].getRange(3, 5);
  z = z.getValue();
  sheetNameArray.push(z);
}
sheetNameArray.forEach(function(e, i){
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(e));
  ss.moveActiveSheet(i+1);
});
```

#### Note :

- It supposes that your script can retrieve the sheet names to `sheetNameArray`.
- The sheet names in `sheetNameArray` are required to be included in the opened spreadsheet.
- The length of `sheetNameArray` is required to be the same with the length of `var sheets = ss.getSheets();`.

#### Reference :

- [moveActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#moveActiveSheet(Integer))

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: thanks. I changed it to an object so I could get the sheet names and the value in cell 3,5 but this was basically it.

Comment: @user718229 I'm glad your issue was solved. If you have any questions, feel free to tell me.